# Can I grant access right to object saved in AWS S3 with the 3rd level api?

Tags: android, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, acl

To upload a file in the S3 bucket, you may use the 3rd level API as :

```
TransferUtility transferUtility = AWSUtils.getTransferUtility(App.getInstance());
TransferObserver observer = transferUtility.upload(AWSUtils.getBucketName(), AWSUtils.getUserPreferredPicturePath(), fileToUpload);
```

Now, if I want to grand access (aka ACL) to this file, how can I do ?

```
AWSUtils.getS3Client(App.getInstance()).setObjectAcl(AWSUtils.getBucketName(), AWSUtils.getUserPreferredPicturePath(), CannedAccessControlList.AuthenticatedRead);
```

This is not working for me ...

**EDIT :**

Ok for the Async. My stacktrace is :

```
Caused by: com.amazonaws.services.s3.model.AmazonS3Exception: Access Denied (Service: Amazon S3; Status Code: 403; Error Code: AccessDenied; Request ID: 7A391FA126C83C0A), S3 Extended Request ID: 47JoAm2dOlNH+eX9fZx+nQiAM1WmPI431+IE99JCZKh90Kr+q1u5T8sDWzhLASJZ
```

My full (Q&D) code is the following :

```
public class SaveProfilePictureOnAWSS3Error extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Void> {
    @Override
    public Void doInBackground(String... params) {

        try {

            String picture_url = params[0];

            File fileToUpload = new File(picture_url);

            TransferUtility transferUtility = AWSUtils.getTransferUtility(getInstance());
            TransferObserver observer = transferUtility.upload(AWSUtils.getBucketName(), "test/" + AWSUtils.getUserPreferredPicturePath(), fileToUpload);


            observer.setTransferListener(new TransferListener() {

                @Override
                public void onStateChanged(int id, TransferState state) {

                    if (state.equals(TransferState.COMPLETED)) {
                        new  updateACL().execute();
                    }
                }

                @Override
                public void onProgressChanged(int id, long bytesCurrent, long bytesTotal) {
                    int percentage = (int) (bytesCurrent / bytesTotal * 100);
                    //Display percentage transfered to user
                }

                @Override
                public void onError(int id, Exception ex) {
                    // do something
                    new MessageToDisplayEvent(ex.getMessage(), true);
                }
            });

        } catch (Exception e) {
            EventBus.getDefault().post(new MessageToDisplayEvent(e.getMessage(), true));
        }

        return null;
    }

    public class updateACL extends AsyncTask<Void,Void,Void>{

        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
            AWSUtils.getS3Client(MilleZimU.getInstance()).setObjectAcl(AWSUtils.getBucketName(), "test/" + AWSUtils.getUserPreferredPicturePath(), CannedAccessControlList.AuthenticatedRead);
            return null;
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: What is not working? Would you please provide more details, like stack trace etc? The upload is asynchronous. Please make sure it's done before you operate on it, say setting ACL.

Comment: @Yangfan see my update.

Answer (score 2):

The stacktrace shows `Access Denied`. That usually means your credentials don't have permission to performance certain operations. Please check the access policy of the credentials. FYI, that particular operation requires `s3:PutObjectAcl` permission. For more information about access policy, see http://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/access_policies.html.

Comment: as the owner, didn't I the possibility to change the permission, as defined in the console ("tick edit Permission")?

Comment: I don't have the full context, so I can't tell where the problem is. However this is definitely a permission issue.

Comment: The bucket is fresh news, so I have the default standard permission for the owner of the bucket (List | Update,Delete |View Permission | Edit Permission). Does this not enough to do everything ?

Comment: There are several access controls involved here. See http://blogs.aws.amazon.com/security/post/TxPOJBY6FE360K/IAM-policies-and-Bucket-Policies-and-ACLs-Oh-My-Controlling-Access-to-S3-Resourc